# Can collection_select be used against yaml files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

My Rails application currently uses **collection_select** to select lookup values for drop downs etc. This has two advantages:

1. The values are consistent
2. The id of the selected value is stored in the database, not the text value

For example:
edit.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :course_type %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :course_type, Lookup.find(:all,:conditions => ["model_name = 'course' and field_name = 'course_type'"]), :id, :lookup_text, include_blank: false,:prompt => "Course Type" %>
</div>
```

course_controller.rb

```
private
  def get_lookups
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    @course_type = Lookup.find(@course.course_type).lookup_text
```

show.html.erb

```
<b>Course type:</b>
<%= @course_type %>
```

My application will be multi-lingual, and Rails handles this by using locale files.

The question is: Is it possible (and sensible) to populate lookup values from yml files, rather than model/tables, and can this be easily extended to handle multiple languages? How could the above code be replaced with yml-based code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution would be to keep translations in the DB, perhaps with our [Traco](https://github.com/barsoom/traco) lib. I suspect it would work with `collection_select`.

If you want to pull options from your translation YML files, I suggest [`options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select). All in all something like:

**en.yml**

```
en:
  my_options:
    one: "Option 1"
    two: "Option 2"
```

**View:**

```
select_tag :foo, options_for_select(t("my_options").invert)
```

Rails i18n gives you a hash if you translate a non-leaf key, like "my_options". You need the `invert` because `options_for_select` expects the text before the value, and a translation hash is the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for both options. I will look into Traco. It seems the options_for_select would return a text value, which is then written to the database field. Coming from a 3NF database background I can see some issues with this - mostly around storing excessive data. I'll accept your answer though: thank you.

Comment: This is too complicated, you can actually use collection_select with .yml translations (without DB).

Comment: Thanks for the .invert

Answer (score 1):

To translate your `collection_select`, you simply create a new model method (let's say, "`name_translated`") which returns your translation from the YAML file:

View:

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name_translated %>
```

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name_translated
    I18n.t(name)
  end
end
```

YAML file:

```
en:
  name1: "Hammer"
  name2: "Plastic sheets"
  name3: "Duct tape"
```

Comment: I would still suggest storing translations in the DB if they need to change when the DB changes, to reduce the risk of them drifting apart. I'm editing your answer just for slight clarification; let me know if you mind.

Answer (score 0):

I use select:

```
<%= f.select :role, MAIN_CONFIG['manager_roles'].map { |s| [s.last, s.first] }, selected: @manager.role %>
```

And my yaml file main_config.yml:

```
manager_roles:
  admin: 'Суперадмин'
  partner_admin: 'Администратор'
  manager: 'Менеджер'
```